# Как изменить ширину блока с кнопками? Где это указывается?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте.

Когда вставил блок, он встал во всю ширину блоку, и кнопка из-за этого стала чуть ниже.
Я сделал блок с кнопкам-поделиться по ширине равной 300px, но это не помогло.  Синяя отметка блока с кнопками стала 300px, но осталась оранжевая полоса в ширину блока.

Как сделать так, чтобы ширина была столько, сколько я укажу?

И как его, например, разместить с правой стороны?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете добавить кнопки соц. сетей и кнопку "узнать больше" в один div, при этом задав кнопке

```
float: right;
```

а соц сетям

```
float: left;
```

если хотите убрать оранжевую полосу задайте блоку с кнопками соц. сетей

```
float: left;
```

но скорее всего и кнопке с "укзнать больше" надо будет добавить

```
float: right;
```

если все начнет летать - лучше заключить иконки соц. сетей и "узнать больше" в один div

Ширина блока на самом деле изменяется, но в HTML "div" без обработки в css растягивается на всю ширину (оранжевая полоса), обходов на самом деле много, float - один из них.